# Coloring stacked area in highcharts in R

Tags: javascript, r, highcharts, r-highcharter, viridis

I wish to color the entire area of the graph in different colors using the `highcharter` package in R.
The below code is merely highlighting the dots in the graph not the entire area as illustrated in the picture below
The data used here is the favorite_pies data inbuilt in the `highcharter` package in R.

```
  hchart('area', hcaes(x = favorite_pies$pie, y = favorite_pies$percent, color = viridis(5))) %>% 
                 hc_colorAxis(stops = color_stops(colors = viridis::inferno(5)))
```

[The current chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gezjC.jpg)

Comment: For an unknown reason, I am not able to run your code (chart is not displayed and I have Highcharts errors in the colsole - #17 and #26. What packages do I actually need except highcharter and viridis?

Comment: @raf18seb you will need to install the 'magrittr' package to use the '%>%' pipe operator in the code.

Comment: Although I figured out how to get the required output. Thanks anyway..